# DateTime.TryParse successfully parsing some numeric numbers

Tags: c#

I have encountered an unexpected issue when parsing a string as a date.

```
DateTime dt;
bool parsed = DateTime.TryParse("119.08", out dt);
```

After running the above code `parsed` is true and `dt` has a date of `8/1/0119`. Why would this value parse as a date? There is an overload of the TryParse that takes an IFormatProvider and DateTimeStyles. Could this be used to resolve the issue.

Comment: do you want that number to be parsed as date? and if yes what is the format?

Comment: @YaserAdelMehraban no, I don't want that parsed as a date.

Comment: See my answer @James

Comment: If your issue is that why the input string is being parsed as valid date time string then this is not an issue as mentioned in my answer. If you have any other issue then kindly clarify in  your post as to what you want to achieve. Your won't need an IFormatProvider implementation as long as the delimiters are consistent in your input string.

Comment: C# tries its best to parse a string to date, and you expect exceptions instead of trying best?

Answer (score 6):

The reason it successfully parses is because of this on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The string s is parsed using formatting information in the current DateTimeFormatInfo object, which is supplied implicitly by the current thread culture.
>   This method tries to ignore unrecognized data, if possible, and fills in missing month, day, and year information with the current date. If s contains only a date and no time, this method assumes the time is 12:00 midnight. If s includes a date component with a two-digit year, it is converted to a year in the current culture's current calendar based on the value of the Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax property. Any leading, inner, or trailing white space character in s is ignored.

So in your situation since 119 cannot be month (1-12) or a day (1-31) it tries its best and makes the assumption it must be year. Not sure about why it decides 08 is month vs day.

You need to tell the parse method what culture to use for parsing. You can use `TryParseExact` or `TryParse`. Here is how you would use `TryParseExact`:

```
CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo( "en-US" );
DateTime.TryParseExact( "119.08", "g", enUS,
                        DateTimeStyles.None, out dt );
// or this format
DateTime.TryParseExact( "119.08", "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm", enUS,
                        DateTimeStyles.None, out dt );
```

And here is some more info which I pulled right from the .NET FCL source code to explain how the parsing works. The first comment relates to your situation.

[image: DateTimeParse]

Comment: Downvoting without a reason will not help me or the OP or the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this is working is because certain countries use the . as the delineator between month and day. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_Europe#Austria.2C_Germany.2C_Switzerland

"119.08" is the equivalent of specifying a new datetime with only the year and month. The code in the TryParse method, first instantiates a DateTimeToken (without initializing the day), which causes the day to get set to 1. It then proceeds to parse the year and month, after which it terminates, returning the result "08-01-0119."  For more details, start with the following link. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeparse.cs,635a8f27ec7b1ec2

The code below would allow you to specify specific formats to allow. In this case, the parse fails.

```
DateTime dt;
bool parsed = DateTime.TryParseExact("119.08", 
    "yyyy-dd-MM hh:mm tt", 
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, 
    out dt );
```

Comment: I new the "." separator was valid but I always figured it need three parts.

Comment: You are correct. I've updated my answer. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

> Why would this value parse as a date?

This will be parsed as a valid date because comma `,`, forward slash `/`, dot `.`, hyphen `-` and space  are treated as valid delimiters for date part of date time data type in C#.

You can see lot of culture specific date time formats at [this](http://www.basicdatepicker.com/samples/cultureinfo.aspx) link. It shows all long date, short date, long time and short time formats across all cultures.

So all of the following will parse successfully except the last two. Colon `:` is a valid delimiter but it is valid only for time part of date time data type. For date part, colon `:` delimiter is invalid.

```
    DateTime dt;
    bool parsed = DateTime.TryParse("119/08", out dt); //returns true
    parsed = DateTime.TryParse("119/08/02", out dt); //returns true
    parsed = DateTime.TryParse("119.08.02", out dt); //returns true
    parsed = DateTime.TryParse("119.08", out dt); //returns true
    parsed = DateTime.TryParse("119-08-02", out dt); //returns true
    parsed = DateTime.TryParse("119-08", out dt); //returns true
    parsed = DateTime.TryParse("119 08 02", out dt); //returns true
    parsed = DateTime.TryParse("119 08", out dt); //returns true
    parsed = DateTime.TryParse("119:08:02", out dt); //invalid as colon : is time sesparator, so API can't figure out date at all
    parsed = DateTime.TryParse("119:08", out dt); //invalid as colon : is time sesparator, so API can't figure out date at all
```

As correctly mentioned by @Lei Yang, C# tries its best to parse a string to a valid date time value instead of throwing exception.
So as long as there are valid delimiters and even if day of the month part is missing then .Net API is able to parse it successfully and produce an output for you.

So in your case `"119.08"` it assumes custom `yyyy.MM.dd` (with dot `.` as delimiter) format based on which it took 119 (number before `.` delimiter) as year then 08 as month (number after `.` delimiter). Since there are no more delimiter characters in your input string so it gives a default value of 1 for day of the month component.

If I try to complete your date string with more delimiters then it gives me full value as shown in the code below:

```
DateTime dt;
bool parsed = DateTime.TryParse("119.08.02", out dt);//gives 02 Aug 0119
```

Comment: The part of your answer about consistency of the arbitrary delimiters and that the `yyyyMMdd` is used does not sound right https://dotnetfiddle.net/ `yyyyMMdd` is surely not the format that would parse `119.08` string.

Comment: I just tested it myself as I have shown in the last most code snippet. When I give two delimters `.` and `$` then the API fails. My project is targeting .Net framework 4.0 just in case if that helps. In the format string `yyyyMMdd` I've not mentioned the delimiter which can be anything in this case e.g. `.` or `$`.

Comment: "But yes, the delimiters should be consistently used in the input string else the parse API will fail." --- this is wrong. The latest code sample is also misleading (it is irrelevant). "In the format string yyyyMMdd I've not mentioned the delimiter which can be anything" --- there is no any "delimiter" in that format allowed at all.

Comment: "it assumes custom yyyy.MM.dd" --- 1. It does not 2. It won't parse it 3. .net parses the `119.08` with some default format, and that is what question about.

Comment: If you mention two different kinds of delimiters e.g. `.` and `$` as show in my last code snippet then it fails. It returns false.

Comment: And that is wrong. It fails not because the "delimiters" are different, but because it does not match the format. It really has nothing to do with them being different. If you are not agree - provide any proof of your words (at the moment everything in your answer is based on assumptions, not facts).

Comment: You are saying - `2. It won't parse it`. But OP has mentioned that it is getting parsed successfully and I'm also able to parse it with OP's code snippet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130059/discussion-between-zerkms-and-rbt).

Comment: Thank you for following up on my answer @zerkms. I've updated my answer to reflect my latest findings.

Comment: "So as long as there are valid delimiters" --- where did you get it from? The whole idea of "valid delimiters" looks not right. Where is it defined?

Comment: @zerkms I have added a link in my post which lists all the short and long date time formats in use across all cultures currently supported in .Net. There you will see all the characters in use namely space, comma, slash, hypen, period etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the suggestions but since the date formats I could be getting could be a verity of valid USA date formats I don't think it will really work. I know I can pass multiple formats but I don't even know every thing that might come up and don't want to miss anything.

At this point I think I'll just do the following.

```
DateTime dt;
string strDate = "119.08";
bool parsed = !strDate.Contains(".") && DateTime.TryParse(strDate, out dt);
```

My application will never use the format that includes a "." so I think this should work for me.

Any problems that might come up that I'm not considering?

Answer (score -1):

From MS docs:

When this method returns, contains the DateTime value equivalent to the date and time contained in s, if the conversion succeeded, or MinValue if the conversion failed.

You can use `ParseExact` method instead:

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

// Parse date-only value with invariant culture.
dateString = "119.08";
format = "d";
try {
   result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
   Console.WriteLine("{0} converts to {1}.", dateString, result.ToString());
}
catch (FormatException) {
   Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format.", dateString);
}
```

Comment: It does not address the question though. "Why would this value parse as a date?" (ps: downvote is not mine)

Comment: If I were an OP I would not be satisfied with it. Why exactly `119.08` is parsed like that? What is the *formal rule*?

Comment: @zerkms I'm wondering the same thing. Why is 119.08 treated as a valid date in the first place?

Comment: @James yep, I'm curious here as well :-) Hence an upvote for the question for me and help in the comments :-)

Comment: This solution doesn't work for my needs since it won't always be in the `"d"` format. It might include time as well.